# Survival analysis with large populations (upscaling sample to population)

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, population, weibull-distribution

Taking the data available from the `survival()` package, we can develop a survival curve and 95% CI, assuming an underlining **weibull distibution**.

```
library(survival)

data(lung)

head(lung)

#create a Surv object
s <- with(lung,Surv(time,status))

#plot weibull survival curves, per sex,
sWei <- survreg(s ~ as.factor(sex), dist='weibull', data=lung)

#
probs <- seq(0.001,0.999,0.001)
pred <- predict(sWei,newdata=list(sex=1),type="uquantile",p=probs,se.fit=TRUE)
val <- cbind(pred$fit,pred$fit-1.96*pred$se.fit,pred$fit+1.96*pred$se.fit)
val <- exp(val)    # convert from log scale to original scale


xlim = range(0,1000)
ylim = range(0,1)
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
plot(0.00001, pch=".", col='white', xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xlab="", ylab="")
lines(val[,1],probs,col="black",lty=1, lwd = 2)
lines(val[,2],probs,col="black",lty=2, lwd = 1)
lines(val[,3],probs,col="black",lty=2, lwd = 1)
```

(Hypothetically) We were then provided with weighting factors of each observation, so that we could scale the sample we have to be representative of a population.

```
lung$weigthsa <- with(lung, ifelse(time < 400, 1000, 
                                  ifelse(time < 7000, 500, 300)))
```

We can continue to create a new model using the same methodolgy and plot

```
#plot weibull survival curves, per sex,
sWei <- survreg(s ~ as.factor(sex), weights = weigthsa, dist='weibull', data=lung)

#
pred <- predict(sWei,newdata=list(sex=1),type="uquantile",p=probs,se.fit=TRUE)
val <- cbind(pred$fit,pred$fit-1.96*pred$se.fit,pred$fit+1.96*pred$se.fit)
val <- exp(val)    # convert from log scale to original scale


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

lines(val[,1],probs,col="red",lty=1, lwd = 2)
lines(val[,2],probs,col="red",lty=2, lwd = 1)
lines(val[,3],probs,col="red",lty=2, lwd = 1)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**So my question is, are we simply allowed to do this?**, given that we see that the width of the CI's for the second model become very small.

**Do we violate any assumptions of survival analysis when upscaling the model to a larger population?**

I ask so, because I similiar question was asked on this [link](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-12/msg00281.html)
Where the answer was given

> > As with any statistical test that uses a null hypothesis, the p-value
> >     for the phtest is dependent on the sample size. These tests were not
> >     developed for such large datasets. In population-based survival
> >     analyses violations of PH assumptions are universal, just as linearity
> >     assumptions are.

But i have found no other supporting literature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even trying to figure out what you have done, the answer is "No, what you've done is wrong". Survival analysis with survey data is *extremely* complicated.  None of the large scale survey data that have proper weights are collected at sufficiently high frequency to support survival analysis -- at best, you can figure out that the event happened some time in the prior year if the data are longitudinal and are collected annually. You don't always know the timing of the life events very well, etc. So many assumptions of the strict "got cancer -- got on therapy -- complied with treatment -- was in clinic under constant observation -- died within this many days" analyses are violated.

The supporting literature, unfortunately, comes literally from two people -- Jerry Lawless and Christian Boudreau, both of University of Waterloo, Canada. A good intro reading would be *Event History Analysis and Longitudinal Surveys* chapter by Lawless in [Chambers and Skinner (2003)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471899879).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have since found this article [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/cjs.5550340202/abstract).From what i understand, if the sampling design (of the study or database) is ignoreable, than minimal is gained from by weighting the data as the estimating function is asymptotically unbiased.

Comment: Yeah... right... show me that design.